# how Install the Delta Lake package on the on-premise environment?

Tags: python, pyspark, debian, delta-lake, data-lake

I want make a data lake for my self without using any cloud service. I now have an Debian server and I want create this data lake with Databricks solution, Delta Lake.

As I search all sample for stablish Delta Lake in could service.

How can I do this in my own server?

Maybe I want create an cluster for store data and doing machine learning. And I want use only python for create Delta Lake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a broad question. The Delta Lake itself is just a library that allows you to work with data in a specific format. To use it you need few things:

- Compute layer that will read & save Delta Lake data. You can run Apache Spark on the local machine or on the [`Hadoop or Kubernetes cluster`](https://c) or work with Delta files using Python or Rust libraries (although you may not get all features available).  Full list of integrations is available [here](https://delta.io/integrations/).
- Storage layer to keep your Delta Lake tables - if you use one server, then you can use local file system, but as data size grows then you need to think about distributed filesystem, like, HDFS, [MinIO](https://min.io/), etc.
- Data access layer - how you will access that data. It could be Spark code, or something like that, but you may need also to expose data via JDBC/ODBC - in this case you may need to setup [Spark's Thrift server](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-distributed-sql-engine.html) or something like that.

Comment: Tanks. I want read a file that is in other server. every  day new file saved in that server. Can i do this only with spark or i need some thing like airflow?

Comment: it depends on how that file is exposed on that server - samba/nfs, etc. airflow could be overkill for such task if it's enough to use scp or something like that

Comment: it is only a csv file. what do you mean of scp? )

Comment: scp - secure copy tool, part of ssh package